# add_update() in my custom Keras layer doesn't update the weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm implementing Center loss: https://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf and I am having problem with updating weights in my layer, which here means updating centers in Center loss. When I print my class_centers like this `tf.print(self.class_centers, summarize=-1, output_stream='file:///tensors.txt')` than they never change. When I print other Variables they seem fine, so the only problem I can think of is that add_update() doesn't do what it should do.

The custom layer:

```
class CenterLossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.5, **kwargs):
        self.alpha = alpha  
        super(CenterLossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print('Center loss input 1 (feature_size): ', input_shape[0][1])
        print('Center loss input 2 (num_classes): ', input_shape[1][1])
        self.class_centers = self.add_weight(name='class_centers',
                                       shape=(input_shape[1][1], input_shape[0][1]),
                                       initializer='uniform',
                                       trainable=False)
        super(CenterLossLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        embeddings, one_hots = x
        tf.print(self.class_centers, summarize=-1, output_stream='file:///tensors.txt')

        batch_centers = K.dot(one_hots, self.class_centers)
        batch_delta = batch_centers - embeddings

        class_delta = K.dot(K.transpose(one_hots), batch_delta)
        counts = K.sum(K.transpose(one_hots), axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1
        class_delta = class_delta / counts
        class_delta = K.in_train_phase(self.alpha * class_delta, 0 * class_delta)

        updated_class_centers = self.class_centers - class_delta
        self.add_update((self.class_centers, updated_class_centers), x[0])

        losses = K.sum(K.square(embeddings - batch_centers), axis=1, keepdims=True)

        return losses

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[1][0], )
```

and the final loss is:

```
def batch_mean_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred, axis=0)
```

where `y_pred` is `losses` from CenterLossLayer.

The weird thing is that even thought the centers are not updating, the center loss is going down with each epoch and the final model is better that the one trained only with Softmax loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I checked out how `add_update()` is used in BatchNormalization layer:

```
self.add_update([K.moving_average_update(self.moving_mean,
                                                 mean,
                                                 self.momentum),
                         K.moving_average_update(self.moving_variance,
                                                 variance,
                                                 self.momentum)],
                        inputs)
```

The thing is that the first argument of method `add_update()` is "updates: Update op" and `moving_average_update()` returns "An operation to update the variable.". So I guess that `add_update()` requires some sort of operation and `moving_average_update()` returns that. I don't know how to create this operation, so instead I did:

```
self.add_update(K.moving_average_update(self.class_centers, updated_class_centers, 0.0), x)
```

so it functions as just replacing `self.class_centers` with `updated_class_centers` and it works.

Even thought it works, I would appreciate if anyone knows how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should do something like this:

```
class ComputeSum(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, input_dim):
    super(ComputeSum, self).__init__()
    self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((input_dim,)), trainable=False)

  def call(self, inputs):
    self.total.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=0))
    return self.total
```

Snippet got from https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#layers-can-have-nontrainable-weighto